# How to view PDF data bytes using SWT Browser

Tags: java, pdf, browser, swt

I have a function that returns a byte array of PDF data, and I want to view it in a Java SWT application.  I do not want to use any jars such as Icepdf, jpedal, etc.  Just SWT and Java.

One obvious solution is to write all the bytes to a file "C:/TEMP/file.pdf" and then call browser.setURL("file://c:/TEMP/file.pdf").  However I want to avoid using temp file if possible.

I tried the following, but it does not work, because the "setText" assumes MIME type text/html.  If only SWT provided a setText(bytes,headers) method!

Any advice how to do this?

```
public class MyBrowser
{
    static byte[] GetPDFData()
    {
        // details omitted
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        browser.setLayoutData(new RowData(600, 300));

        byte[] pdfdata = GetPDFData();

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("Content-Type: application/pdf\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < pdfdata.length; ++i)
            buffer.append((char) pdfdata[i]);
        browser.setText(new String(buffer));
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (shell != null && !shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
            {
                shell.getDisplay().sleep();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you don't even want to uses the OS's temp folder which is designed for scenarios like this?

Comment: Write a new SWT component?

Comment: @Baz - yes I should something portable, like File.createTempFile. But i'd rather not use any file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, well. I give up. It is not ideal, but guess I must use a temp file.  The following works,

```
        byte[] pdfdata = GetPDFData();

        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("twiqd", ".pdf");
        FileOutputStream tempOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        tempOut.write(pdfdata);
        tempOut.close();

        browser.setUrl(tempFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
        shell.pack();
        etc.
```

I have to remember to delete the temp file.